# ASP .Net Core/Razor pages : Keep session alive while working

Tags: c#, .net, session, keep-alive

I have an ASP .Net Core application (Razor Pages). Set `IdleTimeout` to 30 minutes :

```
services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);  
    }
);
```

It works fine except that when the user exceeds 30 minutes he will be redirected to the login page (session expires).
How can I extend the duration automatically while the user is working?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you shouldn't. This would be a security risk in my opinion.

It would be better to get the user to save their changes frequently which in turn will keep the session alive.